# Pycharm CE: Cannot Start the Process: The Working Directory Does not Exist

Tags: python-3.x, directory, pycharm

This is the first time I encounter this issue, I have the CORRECT script path and CORRECT working directory, but when I try to run the code on Python CE, it shows that the file does not exist.

Please see the details in the pictures and code beneath, thank you!
[The Error Message from running the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sM9r3.png)

[My configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqzCG.png)

Comment: Does it help if you remove a space after `Amazon_price_tracker` in Script path & Working directory?

Comment: No it doesn't, the script path and working directory you see are both automatically generated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the correct solution as I quoted from [https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207043685-Problem-with-Error-Cannot-start-process-the-working-directory-does-not-exist-][1]

Odainanna:"

1. Click the drop-down menu with the name of the test in the upper right corner of IntelliJ and click "Edit Configurations".
2. Go to the box that says "Working directory" and delete the contents so that there is no text there."